# Overlapping and trash cell's in my report with JasperReports

Tags: java, excel, jasper-reports

I'm working with *JasperReports* and trying to do a report to *Excel*.

When I try to get the report to excel, I see a terrible report, the cells aren't in the correct place, there are a lot split cells.

I suppose that the problem is in the field that is a List, with the following properties:

```
Position Type: Fix Relative to Top 
Stretch Type: Relative to band height
```

And the field neighbors have the following properties:

```
Position Type: Fix Relative to Top 
Stretch Type: Relative to Tallest object
```

I get the following appearance:

[image]

This is right, but when I get the *Excel* report I get the following:

[image]

I don't know how to fix it.

This is the code to generate the report in *Excel* format.

```java
public boolean exportarAExcel(){
    ServletOutputStream servletOutputStream = null;
    try {
        ExternalContext externalContext = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();

        ServletContext servletContext = (ServletContext) externalContext.getContext();
        String reportPath = servletContext.getRealPath("/rpt/" +this.nombreReporteJasper);

        JasperPrint jasperPrint= JasperFillManager.fillReport(reportPath,this.parametros,
                new JRBeanCollectionDataSource( this.dataSource ));

        HttpServletResponse httpServletResponse =
                (HttpServletResponse) FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getResponse();


        httpServletResponse.setContentType("application/xlsx");
        httpServletResponse.addHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\""+this.nombreSalida+".xlsx\"");
        servletOutputStream =  httpServletResponse.getOutputStream();
        JRXlsxExporter excelExporter=new JRXlsxExporter();
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.JASPER_PRINT, jasperPrint);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.OUTPUT_STREAM, servletOutputStream);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_WHITE_PAGE_BACKGROUND, Boolean.TRUE);

        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_IGNORE_GRAPHICS, Boolean.TRUE);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN, Boolean.TRUE);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_DETECT_CELL_TYPE, Boolean.TRUE);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_ONE_PAGE_PER_SHEET, Boolean.FALSE);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_FONT_SIZE_FIX_ENABLED, Boolean.TRUE);

        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS, Boolean.TRUE);
        excelExporter.setParameter(JRXlsExporterParameter.IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS, Boolean.TRUE);

        excelExporter.exportReport();
        servletOutputStream.flush();
        servletOutputStream.close();
        FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().responseComplete();
        return true;
    } catch (JRException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Exporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        return false;
    } catch (IOException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(Exporter.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    return false;
}
```

This is [the jrxml file](https://gist.github.com/cristianchaparroa/e4ad86676054db4acca4).

Can anyone help me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try setting `IS_COLLAPSE_ROW_SPAN` to false, it can cause some problems when you have cells that merge through multiple rows, and try adding this to report or to code

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.ignore.cell.border" value="false"/>
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.image.border.fix.enabled" value="false"/>
```

Also try setting this two to false

```
IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_ROWS
IS_REMOVE_EMPTY_SPACE_BETWEEN_COLUMNS
```

And if you want to hide the grid lines use this (it will look better even with your current export)

```
<property name="net.sf.jasperreports.export.xls.show.gridlines" value="false"/>
```